# Logging Throwable in main()

Tags: java, throwable

Catching `Throwable` is unadvisable for reasons outlined in different posts. However, would it make sense to have a main structured like below? If the Throwable line is removed, then errors would not be logged.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        launchMyApplication();
    } catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
        //recover if you can, log it if you can't
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //recover if you can (unlikely), log it if you can't
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        //Don't try to recover, but log it
        logger.error("Oops: {}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if the exception is caught by the first cathces would it rethrow to be caught by the last line? Otherwise it wont get past `catch(Exception e)`.

Comment: No I don't rethrow in `main()`.

Comment: +1 Good question. hoping for some good answers also.

Comment: So when would you expect catch Throwable to be invoked?

Comment: There are some interesting information about catching Throwable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097503/best-practices-for-catching-throwable-in-java

Comment: @Jivings Throwable will be invoked if some error occurs, like StackOverflowError, as they are the subclasses of throwable but not Exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementing this way will only handle throwables thrown on the main thread.

The best way to solve this issue is to use [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).